# What to fill in National identification number in DS-160, when I'm temporary resident of an EU country?

Tags: visas, usa, b1-b2-visas

I'm a non-EU citizen(Indian) residing in Belgium & in the process of applying for a B2 - US Tourist Visa, in Belgium. My husband holds permanent residency status in Belgium and I'm his dependent. Holding dependent Resident Permit of Belgium. While filling out DS-160, is it ok that I do not provide the National Identification Number of Belgium? And I mark it as "Does not apply"?

I do not have a specific National ID Number from my home country, other than my passport.

I have filled in my Belgian residential address in my address details in DS-160. Anything else to mention regarding my presence in Belgium, being a dependent resident here? Thanks!

Comment: I'm a US citizen, and so have never completed a Form DS-160. But a web search for "Form DS-160" yields many seconday sources of information about the form. I randomly selected three sources: all three said that if you don't have a National ID number from your home country, you should answer "Does Not Apply" and move on to the next question.

Comment: Do you have an Aadhaar 12-digit number from India?

Comment: @Henry Yes I do have it

Comment: I personally would have thought that would count as a national ID number (what else is it?) but (a) it was not issued by your place of residence in Belgium and the question is in that section, and (b) the general advice on the internet is for Indians to tick the "Does not apply" box in any case.  I would certainly take your Aadhaar card with you to any interview as additional proof of identity plus any evidence of your status in Belgium beyond what is in your passport.

Comment: @Henry The question asks for a national ID number from the applicant's _home country_, not the applicant's _country of residence_.